# Not ordering all column values

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

My Table structure:

**Quran Master**

[image]

QuranPrayed:

[image]

I wanted to make result according to my timestamp.

Means want to get count of sipara according to timestamp.

for that i made following query:

```
SELECT  qm.sipara, Prayed = COUNT(qp.Sipara) 
FROM    QuranMaster qm LEFT JOIN QuranPrayed qp ON qp.sipara=qm.sipara
where qp.TimeStamp between '2013-10-27 19:59:00.000' and '2013-10-28 20:00:00.000'
GROUP BY qm.sipara,qm.OrderID order by qm.OrderID
```

But its not giving result for 0 times prayed siparas.

Its giving as follows:

[image]

It should also show sipara4 as 0, sipara5 as 0...etc.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried using COUNT(ISNULL(qp.Sipara,0))?

Comment: OR try adding on the join, "LEFT JOIN QuranPrayed qp ON 1=1 AND qp.sipara=qm.sipara"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT qm.sipara, 
       Prayed = COUNT(qp.Sipara) 
FROM QuranMaster qm LEFT JOIN 
     QuranPrayed qp ON (qp.sipara = qm.sipara AND qp.TimeStamp >= '2013-10-27 19:59:00.000' AND qp.TimeStamp <= '2013-10-28 20:00:00.000')
GROUP BY qm.sipara,qm.OrderID 
ORDER BY qm.OrderID
```

basically, your WHERE clause was filtering out the rows, so moving your timestamp condition in your WHERE clause to your LEFT JOIN clause, means that you can include all rows form QuranMaster, and then only have the counts of those records in QuranPrayed that meet the timestamp condition, otherwise those records that don't meet the timestamp condition are not joined and hence not included in the count

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that your between for timestamp is dropping the records you want to sum. Do the sum first and then do left join from the master.

```
SELECT  
  qm.sipara
, vsum.Prayed
From QuranMaster qm 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    Select
      qp.sipara
    , Prayed = COUNT(qp.Sipara) 
    From QuranPrayed qp
    GROUP BY qp.sipara
) vsum  
ON vsum.sipara=qp.sipara
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Sipara` field from `QuranMaster` rather than `QuranPrayed` in the `COUNT(...)`

```
SELECT  qm.sipara, 
        Prayed = COUNT(qm.Sipara) 
FROM    QuranMaster qm 
        LEFT JOIN QuranPrayed qp 
            ON qp.sipara=qm.sipara
where   qp.TimeStamp between '2013-10-27 19:59:00.000' and '2013-10-28 20:00:00.000'
GROUP BY qm.sipara,qm.OrderID 
ORDER BY qm.OrderID
```

I would also advise not using `BETWEEN` but `>=` and `<` :

```
SELECT  qm.sipara, 
        Prayed = COUNT(qm.Sipara) 
FROM    QuranMaster qm 
        LEFT JOIN QuranPrayed qp 
            ON qp.sipara=qm.sipara
where   qp.TimeStamp >='2013-10-27 19:59:00.000' 
        and qp.TimeStamp < '2013-10-28 20:00:00.000'
GROUP BY qm.sipara,qm.OrderID 
ORDER BY qm.OrderID
```

Comment: @DStanley First of all, It didn't work because of the `WHERE`. I see a valid answer so i won't write the same things... `BETWEEN` means `>=` and `<=`. In this case i guess that the valid filter would be `>=` and `<`, because if you use `BETWEEN` then entries that are exactly on `2013-10-28 20:00:00.000` would appear both in a filter set `where   qp.TimeStamp between '2013-10-27 19:59:00.000' and '2013-10-28 20:00:00.000'` and in a filter set `where   qp.TimeStamp between '2013-10-27 20:00:00.000' and '2013-10-28 20:01:00.000'`, which i guess is not the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE clause is filtering out parent rows that don't have a child row.  Move that condition to the JOIN:

```
SELECT  qm.sipara, 
        Prayed
FROM    QuranMaster qm 
LEFT JOIN QuranPrayed qp 
    ON qp.sipara=qm.sipara
        AND qp.TimeStamp between '2013-10-27 19:59' and '2013-10-28 20:00'
GROUP BY qm.sipara,
         qm.OrderID 
ORDER BY qm.OrderID
```

Or do the grouping in a subquery:

```
SELECT  qm.sipara, 
        Prayed = COUNT(qm.Sipara) 
FROM    QuranMaster qm 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sipara, 
           Prayed = COUNT(*) 
    FROM QuranPrayed 
    WHERE TimeStamp between '2013-10-27 19:59' and '2013-10-28 20:00'
    GROUP BY qm.sipara ) QP
    ON qp.sipara=qm.sipara
ORDER BY qm.OrderID
```

Comment: getting all sipara...but wrong count...count of sipara for all dates